# Slide in a Layout and replace with another layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I want to create slide in effect like below.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/838/CSSslidy-An-Auto-Generated-Responsive-CSS3-Image-Slider

The differences are

1) I have layout with two images, and when the new image is downloaded in background, one of the existing image has to slide out and this new image has to slide in.
2) User dont need to scroll and see previous images, I want to show only two images at any given time.
3) Its better if the diapered images get disposed.

What i tried so for with no luck
1) Horizontal scroll view- issues is hard to add items dynamically scroll to it while existing images been deletes.
2) ViewPager - http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html,  couldnt get it to work.

what other ways is there, or how to improve what I tried.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and effective tutorial here.

1.http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/implement-slide-in-and-slide-out.html

2.http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/image-slideshow-from-right-to-left-using-viewflipper-in-android/

Basics about animation tutorial here,

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

ViewPager is what you want, hope it'll help.